# ggplot change color regression line to gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a scatterplot with a regression line:

```
ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = bodywt, y = brainwt, color = bodywt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = F, aes(color=..y..)) +
  labs(title = 'Scatter Plot of Body Weight vs. Brain Weight', x = 'Body Weight', y = 'Brain Weight')
```

[image]

However, I want to change the color of the regression line so that it follows the same gradient as the points (based on bodywt) so that the bottom left is dark blue and the top right is light blue. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `ggforce::geom_link2` which however requires to create your regression line manually and add the fitted values to your dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

msleep$.fitted <- predict(
  lm(brainwt ~ bodywt, data = msleep), newdata = msleep
)

ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = bodywt, y = brainwt, color = bodywt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_link2(
    aes(y = .fitted)
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Scatter Plot of Body Weight vs. Brain Weight",
    x = "Body Weight",
    y = "Brain Weight"
  )
#> Warning: Removed 27 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]